# Django create custom decorator

Tags: django, decorator

I'm using Django for my server and I host multiple domains on my single Django installation.

I'm currently performing a check on every incoming request in my view to see if the're visiting www.aaa.com or www.bbb.com.

I would like to put this check in a decorator for obvious reasons but failed to implement this functionality so far. :(

**My homepage view:**

```
def index(request, value=None):

    # Here I check the domain the user wants to visit.
    if request.META['HTTP_HOST'] != "www.aaa.com":
        raise Http404("Requested website is not availble on the server.")

    # Code here

    # Load HTML
    return render(request, 'frontend/homepage.html'})
```

**Login view:**

```
    def login_view(request):

        # Check the domain the user wants to visit.
        if request.META['HTTP_HOST'] != "www.aaa.com":
            raise Http404("Requested website is not availble on the server.")

        # Code here

        # Load HTML
        return render(request, 'frontend/login.html')
```

**My decorator attempt to automate the http_host check:**

```
    def checkClient(func):
        def dosomething(request):
            if request.META['HTTP_HOST'] != "www.aaa.com":
                raise Http404("This domain is not hosted on this server.")
            return request
        return dosomething
```

So I've tried to write my very own decorator but it doesnt work. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close. Instead of returning `request`, your `dosomething` view should call the function `func` that it is decorating.

Secondly, the inner function `dosomething` should handle `*args` and `**kwargs`, so that you can decorate views that take positional and keyword arguments,

```
def checkClient(func):
    def dosomething(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.META['HTTP_HOST'] != "www.aaa.com":
            raise Http404("This domain is not hosted on this server.")
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return dosomething
```